# How find all $f(x+y,y-x)=f(x,y)$

Tags: functions

let the $f(x,y)$ be  Polynomial, such
$$f(x+y,y-x)=f(x,y)$$ 
Find all $f(x,y)$

My idea: let $x+y=u, y-x=v$
then
$$y=\dfrac{u+v}{2},x=\dfrac{u-v}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Only constants can be polynomial solutions.

Let $A(x,y)=(x+y,y-x)$. Then $A(A(x,y))=(2y,-2x)$, so
$A(A(A(A(x,y))))=(-4x,-4y)$. We therefore have
$f(x,y)=f(-4x,-4y)$, so $f(x,y)=f(16x,16y)$ and hence
$f(x,y)=f(16^n x,16^n y)$ for any $n\geq 0$.

The polynomial $Q(t)=f(tx,ty)-f(x,y)$ has infinitely many
roots, so $Q$ must be zero. Decomposing $f$ as a sum of homogeneous polynomials,
$f=\sum_{k=0}^d f_k$ where the homogeneous degree of $f_k$
is $k$ and $f_d\neq 0$, it is easy to see that the degree
of $Q$ is $d$ whenever $d$ is nonzero, so $d$ must be zero.

In other words, $d=0$ and $f$ is constant.